# python MySQLdb: hook function to check connectivity

Tags: python, exception, hook, mysql-python

I have a python script that globally invokes a database connection object with mySQL. There is an insert function `insertToTable(actionDate, action)` which inserts a record to the table. The main section of the script inside `if __name__=="__main__":` runs as an infinite `while` loop for hours/days.

The problem is, the mysql connection object can go unused for many hours which results in timing out of the connection by the MySQL server. I currently use `try` & `except` within the function to catch the exception. However this leads to code repetition since I have to include a try & except block to handle this error in every function.

I would like to know if there is a mechanism in python by which I can hook `insertToTable()` to another function, say `checkConnectivity()`. When `insertToTable()` is invoked, first `checkConnectivity()` is executed and then the execution of `insertToTable()` continues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a decorator that calls the `checkConnectivity` function. Example:

```
def checkConnectivity():
    print 'Checking connection'

def CheckConnectionDecorator(fn):
    def new(*args, **kwargs):
        checkConnectivity()
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return new

@CheckConnectionDecorator
def insertToTable():
    print 'Insertion'

@CheckConnectionDecorator
def anotherQueryFunction():
    print 'Another query'
```

Comment: fantastic. This is exactly what i wanted.